# How to inline machine code in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu

I am using `aarch64-gnueabi-linux-as` to compile my `aarch64` assembly code. All of them are from disassembler. But some of the disassembled code are in wrong syntax. They can't be compiled directly. Considering I have the machine code, I want to insert the compiled code into the assembly code. Is there any way to achieve through GNU assembler?

Comment: It might help if you can show some of the disassembly and why it is in the wrong syntax.

Comment: The GNU assembler has a `.byte` directive if you have a bunch of bytes that you want to insert into the `text` section.

Comment: I have this wild idea: wouldn't a jump in a code region that contains your machine code work?

Comment: Michael Thanks. You are fabulously right!

Comment: http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Incbin.html

Comment: @auselen Thank you. You also provide me another way.